# remove null items from a multidimensional array in C#

Tags: c#

Consider the following array:

```
object[,] output = new object[5,3]{{"A",false,123},{"B",false,12},{"C",true,456},{null,null,null},{null,null,null}};
```

What is the right code if we are going to remove null items?

Comment: You cannot remove any items from an array.

Comment: How do you want to remove the items? The array is fixed size.

Comment: @dymanoid you mean for a multidimensional array? because I know we can use array.where(...) for 1-d array

Comment: @Sefe you right, if it possible we can create a new array and put no null array there.

Comment: LINQ is a *query* language. It doesn't remove anything. If you want to filter data, use `Where`

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to not add arrays of `{null,null,null}` in the first place?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: this is an output array and another method fill it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thanks. But I can't use Where for 2-d arrays

Comment: @Ehsan.Da Could you change the other method to return a list instead of an array so that the `null`s do not need to be passed?

Comment: Do you need an object[,] as output? If not would it be okay to have something like filtered = new IEnumreable<object>(){new {name="A", enabled=false, value=123}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem with multidimensional arrays by using a method as below:

```
public object[,] clear_array_nulls(object[,] input)
    {
        int m = input.GetUpperBound(0);
        int n = input.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
        object[] temp = new object[input.GetUpperBound(0)];
        for (int x = 0; x < m; x++)
            temp[x] = input[x, 0];
        temp = temp.Where(s => !object.Equals(s, null)).ToArray();
        object[,] output = new object[temp.Length, n];
        Array.Copy(input, output, temp.Length * n);
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your null objects always at the end of the multidimentional array?

If so use something like this to remove the null items:

```
    private static void ReDimMultiObjects(ref object[,] arr, int length)
    {
        object[,] arrTemp = new object[length, 3];//New number of objects, and 3 elements in each object
        if (length > arr.Length / 3)//Array Length is always total elements - would be 15 for 5 objects with 3 elements each
        {
            Array.Copy(arr, 0, arrTemp, 0, arr.Length);
            arr = arrTemp;
        }
        else
        {
            Array.Copy(arr, 0, arrTemp, 0, length * 3);
            arr = arrTemp;
        }
    }
```

Then from your program use the following call:

ReDimMultiObjects(ref output, 3);

That would shrink the output array to 3 objects with 3 elements each.